# Is it a sin if one leaves his wife and children and take sannyasam?

Tags: sin, sannyasa

From the sage Pattinathar and Raghavendra left the home and families (for example in the kaliyuga). I thought this is a sin and make a guilty feelings since families are only our depends and we promised to our wife on our marriage ceremony to take care till our death.

Can you please explain?

Comment: That is why to make Pattinathar realize his mistake - Shiva blessed him with Moksha later to his disciple Bhadhuragiri who first got Moksha - my guru told me this. And Sannyasam comes to us and we cant go for Sannyasam. And Ragavendra story is different. So do not leave wife for God realiziation. They are like Lakshmi, Shakti to us like how Shakti is for Shiva.

Comment: Sorry not convinced. Since I already read those stories very well.

Comment: Gautam Buddha is an example of sanyasi who left wife, kid and everything.

Comment: @sv: might be or might not be limitations for yugas'

Comment: @sv: `for example` did you see that????

Comment: It depends upon one's faith in God. If a man has the overwhelming desire for sannyas and has the unwavering faith that God will provide for them, then no. If the man has any doubt that they will be provided for (such as a sense of guilt), then it is a sin.

Comment: its a sin because you take an oath in front of sacred agni during your paanigrahana samskara (marriage)

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with your opinion. Yes. Its a sin.

But a person has a right to request/ask his wife at least once in life time. Not daily. 
So, should take true permission from his wife before taking sanyasam. 
if life mate does not allow to do so, then he does not have any right to leave his dependents, and should not leave his family.

Without life mate permission, if a male person takes sanyasam, then, it becomes a sin and treated/counted as evil karma, and he is forced to reincarnate again to experience and nullify such evil karma in the next life in the form of manglik defect or any other marital defect in the birth chart.

The same rule applies to a mother/father and a son.

e.g. Aadi Shankaracharya. 
He took permission from his mother before taking sanyasam.

One should not leave dependents without their permission.

Comment: I accept your own thoughts and agreed. Any source or references?

Comment: I studied  Shankaracharya life history, and so gave the answer. You may read his life story and know the true dharma.